Proving security of (2,2)-Blakley's Secret Sharing scheme
I am trying to formally prove that the Blakley Secret Sharing scheme is (perfectly) secure, starting with the $(2,2)$ threshold variant. However, I'm encountering an absurdity in my proof, and I'm hoping someone can help me understand what I'm missing.
$(t,n)$-Blakley Secret Sharing
For this purpose, let's go with the following definition of $(t,n)$-Blakley Secret Sharing. Fix some prime $p$ such that $0 < t \leq n < p$. Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{F}_p$ be some secret; all subsequent arithmetic operations are in $\mathbb{F}_p$. The secret will be shared by embedding it as a random point in $t$-dimensional space, with the first coordinate being set to $x_0$. The shares are then $n$ random hyperplanes of dimension $t$ containing the random point. Ignoring the degenerate cases when multiple secret shares represent the same hyperplane, $t$ shares are enough to reconstruct the random point (and hence secret first coordinate) because the hyperplanes they represent intersect at said point. Below is a description of the secret share generation procedure, $\text{Share}$, for $(2,2)$-Blakley Secret Sharing.
$\underline{\text{Share}(x_0)}:$
$y_0 \xleftarrow{\\\$} \mathbb{F}_p$
$a_1, a_2 \xleftarrow{\\\$} \mathbb{F}_p$
$b_i \xleftarrow{} y_0 - a_i x_0$
$s_i \xleftarrow{} (a_i, b_i)$
$\text{return } (s_1, s_2)$
The exact reconstruction algorithm is not relevant to proving (perfect) security, so I'll omit it here.
Security argument
Let $\mathbf{X}$ be the random variable corresponding to the secret, with arbitrary distribution $\Pr[\mathbf{X}]$. Let $\mathbf{Y}$ be the random variable corresponding to the random y-value of the embedded point; note that $\Pr[\mathbf{Y} = y_0] = \frac{1}{p}, y_0 \in \mathbb{F}_p$. Let $\mathbf{S_1} = (\mathbf{A_1}, \mathbf{B_1}), \mathbf{S_2} = (\mathbf{A_2}, \mathbf{B_2})$ be the random variables corresponding to the two secret shares. To show security, we argue that the distribution of a single secret share is identical regardless of the underlying secret value*; that is, $\forall x_0, x'_0, a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{F}_p, \Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i) \vert \mathbf{X} = x_0] = \Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i) \vert \mathbf{X} = x'_0]$.
The argument is as follows: let's consider some arbitrary secret $x_0 \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and secret share $s_i = (a_i, b_i) \in \mathbb{F}_p^2$. Then,
$\Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i) \vert \mathbf{X} = x_0]$
$= \Pr[b_i = \mathbf{Y} - a_i \mathbf{X} \vert \mathbf{X} = x_0]$
$= \Pr[b_i = \mathbf{Y} - a_i x_0]$
$= \Pr[\mathbf{Y} = a_i x_0 + b_i] = \frac{1}{p}$
An absurdity
It seems that the above argument shows the $(2,2)$-Blakley Secret Sharing scheme has perfect secrecy, but the result fails a simple consistency check. Specifically, it implies that the prior distribution of a secret share is $\frac{1}{p}$ (i.e. $ \forall a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{F}_p, \Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i)] = \frac{1}{p}$). However, there are $p^2$ possible values for a secret share, due to there being two coordinates that range over $\mathbb{F}_p$. This leads to an absurdity where the sum of the probabilities of disjoint events spanning the outcome space exceeds 1 (i.e. $\sum\limits_{a_i, b_i} \Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i)] = \sum\limits_{a_i, b_i} \frac{1}{p} = (p^2) \frac{1}{p} = p > 1$).
$\forall x_0, a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{F}_p, \Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i) \vert \mathbf{X} = x_0] = \frac{1}{p} \implies \Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i)] = \frac{1}{p}$
$$\Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i)]$$
$$= \sum\limits_{x_0} \Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i) \land \mathbf{X} = x_0]$$
$$= \sum\limits_{x_0} \Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i) \vert \mathbf{X} = x_0] \times \Pr[\mathbf{X} = x_0]$$
$$= \sum\limits_{x_0} \frac{1}{p} \times \Pr[\mathbf{X} = x_0] = \frac{1}{p}$$
I take this absurdity to mean that I've made a mistake in my argument. Can anyone help spot it?


*I've also seen an alternative definition of perfect secrecy that the posterior distribution of the underlying secret is independent of knowing an under-threshhold number of shares (e.g. $\Pr[\mathbf{X} = x_0 \vert \mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i)] = \Pr[\mathbf{X} = x_0]$). 

Edit: The randomness in this setup comes from the uniform choice
of $a_i,b_i,y_0,$ there are $p^3$ possible values equally likely and each of the values for $S$ occurs $p$ times. So the probability of each value of $S$ is $p/p^3$ yielding $1/p^2,$ thus no contradiction.
Your confusion stems from the fact that you ignored the effect of the secret $x_0$ in your sum giving total probability $p>1.$ Note that $b_i$ depends on the uniformly chosen $y_0$ as well via the equation
$$
b_i = y_0 - a_i x_0
$$
and for a fixed $x_0$ there is only one unique $y_0$ (out of the possible $p$ equiprobable values) that give the specific value of $b_i$. This "scales down" the probabilities in your sum by a factor $1/p,$ or in other words your sum
$$\sum\limits_{a_i, b_i} \Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a_i, b_i)],$$
is not over disjoint events and yields a given $b_i$ exactly $p$ times, repeating each event $p$ times.

IIUC, you are saying that the error in my reasoning is the (implicit) assumption that $\Pr[\cup\limits_{a,b \in \mathbb{F}p}} \mathbf{S_i} = (a,b)] = \sum\limits{a,b \in \mathbb{F}_p} \Pr[\mathbf{S_i} = (a,b)]$. I'm not sure why this is false; it seems to me that the event that a secret share is some value $(a, b)$ is disjoint from it being any other value $(a', b') \neq (a,b)$, in which case the equality should hold.
